# Restrict editing a column in a datagrid

Tags: flex4, flashbuilder4

Good evening stackoverflow...I have a problem see. I want to be able to restrict the input of user to only ("0-9"),I know how to implement this in a text input since it has the restrict function. My question is how can I implement a restrict in a datagrid?
Please help me..thnx

Answer (score 1):

Create an item editor with a text input as a component and then restrict it. Don't forget to set column to editable="true"